On mod 2 intersection number
On page 78 of the book Differential Topology by Guillemin and Pollack is presented the following
Theorem: If $f_0 , f_1 : X\to Y$ are homotopic and both transversal to $Z$, then $I_{2}(f_0 , Z)=I_{2}(f_1 , Z)$.
In the proof it is stated that if $F:X\times [0,1] \to Y$ is a homotopy of $f_0$ and $f_1$ then the authors mention that we can assume that $F$ is transversal to $Z$.
Why can I assume this fact?

Please ask only one question per post.

This fact (used frequently in Guillemin & Pollack) is a consequence  of the Extension Theorem on p. 72. This, in turn, is a technical generalization of the Transversality Homotopy Theorem on p. 70.

Well, $\hat{X}:=X\times [0,1]$ is a manifold with boundary, with $\partial\hat{X}=(X\times{0})\cup(X\times{1})$. Then if $F:\hat{X}\to Y$ is the homotopy of $f_0$ and $f_1$, why $F$ satisfies the hypothesis of Extension theorem?

Because the hypothesis is precisely that $f_0$ and $f_1$ are transverse to $Z$; this is the condition that $\partial F = F|_{\partial\hat X}$ is transverse to $Z$.

So, in our case $C:=\partial\hat{X}$ (from theorem of extension) which is closed, really?

Yes. :) That’s it.

All right, thanks a lot.
